# How to Select All Text in TextBox After textBox.Setfocus Using Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to select all the text in a textbox of an Access form when I click (or double click) into it. i tried the following code, unsuccessfully:

```
Me.txt_CompraPreco.SelStart = 0
Me.txt_CompraPreco.SelLength = Len(Me.txt_CompraPreco)
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you place that code? Which event?

Comment: I placed the code in the OnEnter event, OnGotFocus, Click and DblClick...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the code shown below. If it doesn't work, place a breakpoint at the first line of code. If it doesn't stop on your breakpoint, then your event is not recognized.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub txt_CompraPreco_Click()
    If Len(Me.txt_CompraPreco & "") = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Me.txt_CompraPreco.SelStart = 0
    Me.txt_CompraPreco.SelLength = Len(Me.txt_CompraPreco)
End Sub
```

Comment: hello Wayne. but this is the code I'm using, unsuccessfully.

Comment: Did you try the debugging steps I suggested? As a test, delete ALL events except the 'Click' event and follow the debug steps.

Comment: I tryed. unfourtunately, it didn't work. I kept the Click event but failed. nothing happens.

Comment: What happened when you put the breakpoint on the first line of code? Did it stop there when you clicked within the text box?

Comment: You are missing the point! There will be NO ERROR! If you place a breakpoint in that code, then click on the text field (with the form active!), there should then be a HALT in the code. If there is no halt, then your event is not recognized. Is the code halting where the breakpoint is? Please read carefully and respond in detail about what you did.

Comment: my event is being reconized. that's what I want to make clear.

Comment: Then add the following as the first line of your subroutine, remove any breakpoints and then run your test.  What is displayed in the Immediate Window?   Debug.Print "Len=" & Len(Me.txt_CompraPreco & "")

Comment: Wayne. I run the compact and repair many times, unsuccessfully. now, I decided to run one more time and it is working now! thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know why those erros persists even after running compact & repair so many times. why?

Comment: I fix the code, debug it, save it and close Access. then, I open it again and the same code doen't work anymore. then, I run compact & repair but, it doesn't fiz it. I run once more, then, it works again. why? why? why?

Comment: Add the debug.print I suggested. Then when it doesn't work, see what is displayed. If nothing, then your event did NOT fire and that will need to be taken care of.

Comment: the hole Office is bugged. the same happens with Excel, Powerpoint... thanks anyway and happy new year.

Comment: Code works perfectly. When is DblClick event just add `DoCmd.CancelEvent` at the end to cancel default event behavior. More info at [DoCmd.CancelEvent Method (Access)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836964.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a solution regarding this problem, I have the same issue, however, I have a solution to it, I'm not sure if it's efficient, but here's my code:

```
'Declare a flag
Public flagDblClick As Boolean

'Double click event
Private Sub txtbox_DblClick (Cancel As Integer)
  flagDblClick = True
End Sub

'Mouse up Event
Private Sub txtbox_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X as Single, Y as Single)
  If flagDblClick Then
    flagDblClick = False
    txtBox.SelStart = 0
    txtBox.SelLength = Len(txtBox.Value)
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This gave me a great idea, Thanks! I used a counter and every second click was highlight all. This way the user could click after the full selection and then just change what they needed.

Answer (score 0):

This code will resolve your problem (use with userform).

```
txt_CompraPreco.SetFocus
Me.txt_CompraPreco.SelStart = 0
Me.txt_CompraPreco.SelLength = Len(Me.txt_CompraPreco)
```

Answer (score 0):

My trial and error found this.
If your textfield is formatted as a Standard Number and you have **set the decimal places to a certain length**, you will run into trouble when you enter a single digit.  For example if your decimal places in the field properties is set to 2 and you enter "1", you will display "1.00".  To get the entire field (1.00) selected, you must specify the .Text property when you determine the .SelLength (not the default .Value property)

```
Me.txtYourFieldname_GotFocus
  Me.txtYourFieldName.SelStart = 0
  Me.txtYourFieldName.SelLength = Len(Me.txtYourFieldName.Text)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Dim bSelect As Boolean

Private Sub fieldX_Click()
    If bSelect Then 
        'Select text only at first mouse click then user can click again
        'and is able to put mouse pointer where he prefers
        Me.fieldX.SelStart = 0
        Me.fieldX.SelLength = Len(Me.fieldX)
        bSelect = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub fieldX_GotFocus()
    bSelect = True
    'Select text if field got focus via keyboard, Enter or TAB
    'this is not enough if field got focus via mouse click
    Me.fieldX.SelStart = 0
    Me.fieldX.SelLength = Len(Me.fieldX)
End Sub
```