# In Access VBA how does one keep a textbox active and select all its contents after Enter key

Tags: vba, ms-access, textbox

In an Access form I am using a textbox to filter an unbound subform. I want to allow the end user to quickly perform quick sequential searches. After the Enter key is pressed to perform a first search, I want the cursor/focus to remain in the text box and the current search text to be selected. In this way the user can directly start entering a new query, replacing the old search text.

I tried the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557496/how-to-select-all-text-in-textbox-after-textbox-setfocus-using-access-vba/27557805) question, but due to the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, the selection always gets lost:

Answer (score 2):

The solution I came up with is to intercept the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key press. It is important to cancel the event, otherwise the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key will remove the selection.

```
Private Sub txtSearch2_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
        Call Search
        If Len(Me.txtSearch2.Text & "") = 0 Then Exit Sub
        Me.txtSearch2.SelStart = 0
        Me.txtSearch2.SelLength = Len(Me.txtSearch2.Text)
        DoCmd.CancelEvent
    End If
End Sub
```